# How to take picture by the volume up button with showing any popup in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using JPSVolumeButtonHandler, but in this I got the volume up button action. But in this ringer and volume button popup is showing. How to take picture?

Comment: Readibility improvements

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 8 you can add an observer to the notification

`_UIApplicationVolumeUpButtonDownNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                  selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
                                  name:@"_UIApplicationVolumeUpButtonDownNotification"
                                  object:nil];
```

If you are using `UIImagePickerController`, you able to capture the event and use it to call `TakePicture` with a custom view.

On top of that, `UIImagePickerController` ensures that pressing volume up won't change the volume.

Or you can use thirdparty library like, [JPSVolumeButtonHandler](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSVolumeButtonHandler).

**Update :**

you can do something like,

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview: volumeView];
```

Don't forget to `@import MediaPlayer;`

refer this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/index.html) for more detail.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I don't want volume popup . I said i got the action but popup also appearing.